# Call a @Autowired Repository from a static context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster, autowired

I have a createEntity method that is static, because i need to call it from other entities, inside this method, i need to call a repository, but logically i can't do it because it's non static.

```
public static Client createEntity(EntityManager em) {
   default_operation = operationRepository.save(OperationResource.createEntity(em));
}
```

I wouldn't ask if i hadn't my head blown away by this, i tried to use @Autowired constructors as other solution suggested but this won't work for a repository.

If anyone has an idea, or a workaround, i would appreciate it!

Comment: If you have no other option you can get the bean from the application context. Save it in a static field when you initialize it and access it from `createEntity` (you also need to somehow make sure that it's already initialized). Doing what werner suggested in his answer will be much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using static methods causes problems (not only in Spring). One of the reasons is that the autowired properties of a class are not available in a static context. They are only injected during certain stages of [Spring's lifecycle](http://www.wideskills.com/spring/spring-bean-lifecycle).

You should declare the class that contains the `createEntity` method as a Spring bean (for example with `@Component`). Then you can inject this bean (with `@Autowired`) in all other classes that need to call `createEntity`.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the class is a Test class

Comment: You can also use '@Autowired' in test classes. You only might need to provide a Spring configuration for your test. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25317360/2129801) helps

Comment: So, from a test class, i could create a property of type ClientTest with @Autowired annotation?

Comment: Yes, check the example [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/spring-junit-test-example/). Especially the class 'JUnitSpringExample'

Answer (score 0):

I DO NOT recommend this, but because of any reason if you can't change the original class (to a singleton), you can consider the below approach which calls the `createEntity(entityManager)` inside [@PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) method:

```
public class MyRepository {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private static Client client;

    @Autowired
    public MyRepository(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //Now call your createEntity(entityManager) method
        client = EntityUtils.createEntity(entityManager);
    }

}
```