# Unit test not running using maven

Tags: java, maven, junit5

I am not able to run my unit test using maven. I tried using mvn clean install and mvn test to run the test, but is not providing the expected result.

I have included the following dependencies :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams-test-utils</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <!--include manifest in repository jar-->
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The test class contains the following nomenclature and annotation :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE,
    classes = {TruckIdLookupService.class, TimescaleConfiguration.class})
public class TestClassName {
```

The method name as following annotation and name:

```
@Test
void testMethodName() throws Exception {
```

I am able to get expected result in Intellij but maven is not running the tests.

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ truckmsg-processor ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: You will have to provide more information. For example maven error output.

Comment: Did you run the maven command mvn clean package or mvn clean install

Comment: @michalk : Stackoverflow did not allowed me to add code in the start. I have added the needful details

Comment: @Sambit : Yes I did maven clean install. Thanks

Comment: Is it running your test cases now ?

Comment: @Sambit : No. Thanks. I have updated the post.

Comment: Can you try to comment out <plugins>...all code ...</plugins> and try to run.

Comment: @Sambit Tried commenting the plugin part.It did not help.

Comment: You are simply using the wrong dependency. You have to use junit-jupiter-engine instead of junit-jupiter-api ....Ah furthermore you have to name your class according to the naming conventions like `*Test.java` as a unit test...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the junit Jupiter dependency helped :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That's a good one. It won't work using ```junit-jupiter-api```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your system is not injecting the correct class correctly?

Checking my code in some projects, I notice that I have the following notation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317009/what-does-this-do-runwithspringjunit4classrunner-class) you can see what it does.

Comment: I guess OP wanted to use junit 5. Why would he downgrade his version to 4?

Comment: @UrbanoJVR : Added the dependency suggested. It did not help. Thanks

Comment: Oh yes, fatal error. You are using junit jupyter api and I post junit. Have you tried adding the Jupyter API version 5.5.0-M1 tag? (I do not think it works, but it can be proven)

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = App.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
public class BulkTests {
@Test
     public void test1() {
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this dependency helped:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```