# Spring Hibernate NullPointerException Dependency Injection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa

I have a maven project.It has a dao class,an entity class and a junit test case.I am using dependency injection for the dao class but it gives a null pointer exception.I know this is a common error faced in spring but they say this happens when we use the new operator to create an instance of a spring component but I haven't used the new operator for the dao class which is the only class with the @Component annotation.

**Entity Class**

```
package com.lti.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Sport {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int sportId;
    private String sportName;
    
    
    public int getSportId() {
        return sportId;
    }
    public void setSportId(int sportId) {
        this.sportId = sportId;
    }
    public String getSportName() {
        return sportName;
    }
    public void setSportName(String sportName) {
        this.sportName = sportName;
    }
}
```

**Dao Class**

```
package com.lti.dao;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class GenericDao {
    
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    
    @Transactional
    public Object save(Object e) {
        Object obj=em.merge(e);
        return obj;
    }
    
    public Object fetchById(Class c1,Object id) {
        return em.find(c1,id);
    }
    
}
```

**SportTest**

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.lti.dao.GenericDao;
import com.lti.entity.Sport;

public class SportTest {

    @Autowired
    private GenericDao dao;
    
    @Test
    public void add() {
        Sport s=new Sport();
        s.setSportName("Football");
        dao.save(s);
    }
    
}
```

**app-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Loading annotated beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.lti.dao" />

    <!-- DataSource configuration -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" init-method="createDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
        <property name="username" value="hr" />
        <property name="password" value="hr" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Spring/Hibernate Integration Settings -->
    <!-- This bean entry below will create the EntityManagerFactory
        & EntityManager object for us. Also we don't need a separate
        META-INF/persistence.xml file as all the required ORM settings
        can be done within this bean configuration itself -->
    <bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.lti.entity" /> <!-- Location of @Entity classes -->
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- This bean entry will take of managing the transactions(begin/commit/rollback) in our code -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Enabling support for @Transactional annotation -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    
</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.lti.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.30.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>18.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate SportTest class with @SpringBootTest

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.lti.dao.GenericDao;
import com.lti.entity.Sport;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class SportTest {

@Autowired
private GenericDao dao;

@Test
public void add() {
    Sport s=new Sport();
    s.setSportName("Football");
    dao.save(s);
}

}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use spring boot.There should be a way to do it without spring boot too right.Its a pretty simple example what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can also fix this without Spring boot, but you have to tell spring to scan annotations in your test class  You will probably need the SpringJUnit4Runner. You should also show the exception (stack trace) to us. Have a look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317009/what-does-this-do-runwithspringjunit4classrunner-class/53383426